# How to add an old project to maven tool to do update and modifications in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, maven

How to add old project to maven build tool to do updations and modifications.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then ask a proper question.

Comment: What do you mean? You want a non-maven project to be a maven project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a shot in the dark at what you mean. If you go to your project in Eclipse and right click on it and go to `Configure`->`Convert To Maven Project` it will display a dialogue box for you to add your `Groupe Id`,`Artifact Id`,`Version`,`Packaging`,and the `Name`.

Assuming you have maven installed. If you don't you can go to [Maven's instructions on installing maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) once you've downloaded the proper `.zip` file.

Comment: Basically we are using very old project it has developed before 7 years ago.I am not getting all the dependencies,it has showing so many errors in ecllipse.